# get load balancer healthchecks in boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-elb

I create a load balancer and a health check for it, and afterwards I want to verify the health check has been set correctly for the load balancer.

I can't seem to find a way to retrieve the healthcheck **(meaning the healthcheck definition)** for the load balancer from the load balancer object.

Also, I might want to use an existing health check for a different load balancer.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

ELB health checks are recorded in CloudWatch, so you need to get this data from CloudWatch, not ELB.

Here is the guide for [CloudWatch and Boto](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudwatch.html).

You can use the `get_metric_statistics` API call to get this data. You can see how to use it [here](https://gist.github.com/beaufour/1838317)

**EDIT:**

From your comments below: So you've created an endpoint on your EC2 nodes and you're using ELB health checks to keep testing your endpoints and you want to retrieve the status of those health checks.

You can't get this information from an "ELB Object". Depending on the particular data you want to retrieve you have 2 options:

1. If you just want the number of health hosts, you can do this by querying the HealthyHostCount metrics for each AZ your ELB is working with. [Read more about this metric.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html#d0e9258)
2. If you want the status of each particular instance you need to submit a [ec2:DescribeInstanceHealth](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstanceHealth.html) API Call. Thankfully, this is build into [boto](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/elb.html#boto.ec2.elb.ELBConnection.describe_instance_health).

On a side note, you should try to provide a little more detail in your questions in order to get the right answer faster. Hope this is the info you need :)

Comment: Hi, that is not exactly what I meant: 
I can't seem to find a way to retrieve the healthcheck  **(meaning the healthcheck definition)** for the load balancer from the load balancer object.

Comment: "the healthcheck definition" is ambiguous and is not a term used by AWS, at least to my knowledge. Can you be more specific and detailed about what exact information you're trying to retrieve? :)

Comment: I create a healthcheck with for "/deployments/status" with a 5 second interval. I want to get back endpoint: "/deployments/status" interval: 5

Answer (score 0):

I think what you were after is available like this

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto.ec2
import boto.vpc
import boto.ec2.elb

REGION="us-east-1"

# Connect
conn = boto.ec2.elb.connect_to_region(REGION)

# Get all ELB data for a single ELB to simplify code here
ELBset=  conn.get_all_load_balancers(load_balancer_names=[put ELB name here])
for ELB in ELBset:
    print ELB.health_check.target
    print ELB.health_check.healthy_threshold
    print
    print dir(ELB.health_check)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.